# How to make the country name to be a part of the URL in Asp.net core Razor pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

We developed a website using ASP.net core Razor Pages so we have some pages in the website served through URLs like

```
Domain/Solutions
Domain/solutions/details/1
Domain/aboutus
```

and other many links of course

After completing the development the customer requested to allow the user to select the company branch before browsing the website so the home page of the site will contain multiple cards one for each branch, for Example, "Dubai Branch, USA Branch, ...."
If the user clicked Dubai Branch for example we need all the URLs to contain that branch as a parameter like following

```
Domain/dubai/solutions
Domain/dubai/solutions/details/1
Domain/dubai/aboutus
```

We need to catch "dubai" as a parameter with all the subsequent requests to filter the content of the pages accordingly and to do this change at a minimal cost, first is that applicable? how to achieve that without many changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark part of a URL as a param like that

```
Domain/{branch}/solutions
Domain/{branch}/solutions/details/1
Domain/{branch}/aboutus
```

so you will be able to read it in your razor page behind code and customer will be able to sent there *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using Area like dubai,usa etc but you need to create separate code for each area.
another option is dynamic routing .